# Caching a Dynamic Laravel-based Progressive Web App for Offline Mode

Tags: laravel, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, lamp, mobile-application

I am currently in the process of converting a dynamic Laravel-based web application into a PWA.

Specifically, I am trying to get the offline caching for my app to apply across the entire code structure.

Ultimately, if a user saves the app to their mobile device after logging in then they should be able to use all the pages/features offline with caching which typically involves creating objects using front-end forms, etc.

So far, I have installed the Composer package 'Laravel PWA' to my app which all works as expected.

However, the next step is to get offline mode working for every route of the app.

If someone could help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.